# TypeScript Function returning set of Functions

Tags: typescript, signature

I'm trying to port the following vanilla JS code to TypeScript to better define return types for all functions. This code exports a single function, `resource`. When called, `resource` returns an object containing other functions.

The type signature seems to disappear when using the resource in the `Demo` class, initialized in the constructor. One approach to this would be to define an interface for `resource`. However, I can't seem to define an interface for `resource` **without repeating** the parameters that are already defined in `doThingOne()` and `doThingTwo()`. My current attempts have all lead me to having to duplicate the signatures. How should I approach this to keep things DRY?

```
function resource(someVar) {

    function doThingOne(p1 = '') {
        return Promise.resolve('thing one ' + someVar + p1);
    }

    function doThingTwo(p1 = '') {
        return Promise.resolve('thing two ' + someVar + p1);
    }

    return {
        doThingOne,
        doThingTwo
    };
}

class Demo {
    resource1;

    constructor() {
        this.resource1 = resource('resource1');
    }
}

const issues = new Demo();
issues.resource1 // no type information for resource1
```

Comment: There are multiple different return types that you could apply to `resource`, for example `{ [key: string]: (string) => Promise<string> }`. If you want to be specific about the keys without repeating the return type, alias it; `export type MyType = (string) => Promise<string>`.

Comment: What have you tried ? If this is the exact structure, I copied it to a ts file, added `export = resource` and it works exactly as expected no extra types required

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Ah, thanks. I simplified my scenario too much. Updating...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want to type a member as being the result type of a function.

The simplest way to do this, would be to do this would be to let the compiler infer it based on assignment:

```
class Demo {
    constructor(name: string, public resource1 = resource(name)) {

    }
}

const issues = new Demo("resource1");
issues.resource1 // correct type
```

If this is not practical, you can get the return type, in one of two ways:

**In Typescript 2.8**

Use the `ReturnType<T>` conditional type. (2.8 is unreleased at the time of writing, but will be released in March 2018, you can get it via `npm install -g typescript@next`)

```
class Demo {
    public resource1: ReturnType<typeof resource>
    constructor() {

    }
}
```

**Pre 2.8**

You can extract the type from the function using a helper function and a dummy variable:

```
// Dummy function, just used to extract the result type of the function passed as the argument
function typeHelper<T>(fn: (...p:any[]) => T): T{
    return null as T;
}
// Dummy variable, null at runtime, but it's type is inferred as the result of the `resource function
let dummy = typeHelper(resource);

// Create a type definition based on the type of dummy
type resourceReturnType = typeof dummy;


class Demo {
    public resource1: resourceReturnType
    constructor() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for factory function once there is class instance that can hold state (which is `someVar` in case of `resource` function):

```
class Resource {
    constructor(private someVar: string);

    doThingOne(p1 = '') {
        return Promise.resolve('thing one ' + this.someVar + p1);
    }

    doThingTwo(p1 = '') {
        return Promise.resolve('thing two ' + this.someVar + p1);
    }
}

class Demo {
    resource1 = new Resource('resource1');
}
```

They can be refactored to single class if `Demo` isn't supposed to do anything else.

Comment: My example code is a simplification of my actual problem. I can't rewrite it to match.

Comment: How can it be answered then? The answers are as good as the question is. Code-related SO questions should contain http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .